# Cannot run paramiko-expect on windows

Tags: python, cygwin, paramiko

I get following error when ran on windows -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo2.py", line 5, in <module>
    from paramikoe import SSHClientInteraction
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramikoe.py", line 17, in <module>
    import termios
ImportError: No module named termios
```

When I searched about it, some articles said it required UNIX like environment, and workaround can be to run using Cygwin.

I installed Cygwin, but still can't run the script.

I'm new to python, can anybody help me with this? How can I make paramiko-expect work on windows?

Comment: Are you using the Cygwin Python and Cygwin paramiko? If not, I'd start there.

Comment: I'm using cygwin only but dont know somehow not able to use cygwin python, i tried few articles available on the internet, but didn't work. Can you provide me the correct article?

Comment: I don't know Python, but the few Python things I have run on Cygwin have worked just fine. Just use the setup program that you used to install Cygwin to also install the Cygwin versions of these applications. Launch the application, and when you get to the select package screen, search for and select "python", then do the same for "paramiko".

Comment: I've retried exactly that but seems to be something wrong .... Will try to figure out what the hell is wrong with my setup...

Comment: Well, if you have a Cygwin Python installed AND a normal Windows Python, you'll need to verify your path inside of Cygwin to make sure you're running the correct one. "which python", or "type -a python" should do the trick.